# How can I rewrite a string without specific words?

Tags: assembly, arm

Alright so the trouble is not detecting the word. The issue I am having is the process of actually rewriting the string without the word that needs removal.

I loop through the string, and then use my 'detection' algorithm to find the word. I keep an index of the first character of the word in a register for usage later (let's call it `badWordIndex`).

I then remove the word by traversing through the entire string again. Once I get to the `badWordIndex`, I add #3 to the index of the string mid-loop so that I can skip the specified word and it won't be stored by my `strb` instruction.

The memory map doesn't appear to be skipping the detected word as I debug. It loads the characters of it like any other word, stores them, and continues (based on the red hex's in the memory map).

Anyone know what could be going wrong? How could I do this in an alternative fashion?

```
        AREA Question_1, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY
        ldr r0, =STRING1 ;r0 points to STRING1 so that it can be accessed and used
EoS     equ 0
SpaceCh equ 32
        ldr r2, =STRING2 ;r5 points to STRING2 so that it can be accessed and used.

        ;'Detection Algorithm', it jumps to the 'remove' branch after an index of "the" substring is found.


remove  mov r0, r6
Loop    ldrb r3, [r0], #1
        strb r3, [r2], #1 ;POST-INDEXED
        cmp r0, r4 ;compare r0 to index of "the" substring..
        beq delete ;..otherwise add 3 to r0 so it skips the "the" substring thus 'deleting' it.
        cmp r3, EoS ;compare r3 to null ascii char..
        bne Loop ;.if they aren't equal, continue traversing the string.
        mov r0, r6
        b Case1
delete  add r0, r0, #3  ;add 3 to r0 so that it skips the "the" substring- this does not work as intended..

        b Loop ;continue traversing string since we know that Case1 is not complete.
skip            ;skip removal since no "the" substring exists.

endless b endless ;loop endlessly as requested in instructions for assignment.

STRING1 dcb "and the man said they must go" ;String1
;EoS        dcb "" ;null char in ascii
;SpaceCh    dcb " " ;space char in ascii
STRING2 dcb " " ;the destination of the string after all "the" words are removed.
        END
```

Comment: Without seeing your code it's nearly impossible to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: It's unclear what `r4` and `r6` have been initialized to. Some obvious issues are that you're looking for a byte with the value 0 even though you haven't placed such a byte after `STRING1` (use `dcb "foobar",0` to get a NUL-terminated string), and that you've only reserved space for a single byte at `STRING2`.

Comment: What about the *second* `"the"` in the string? You add 3 to skip, not 4 (to include a space) so `"they"` would contain your substring too. Also your `strb r3, [r2]` has stored the character before testing if it the start of the substring. So you skip the wrong 3 characters.